# Как сделать маску в css?

Tags: css, css3

как вот сделать вот такое при помощи css а именно цифру

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может Вы это сами знаете, но обычно такое делают в графических редакторах: Если работать с пикселями - Adobe Photoshop, если с вектором - Adobe Illustrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с использованием того же свойства `mix-blend-mode`, что уже предложил @Nikita, но чуть ближе к показанному вами результату. [Поддержка действительно слабенькая](https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode), но если учесть, что значение `difference` работает даже в браузерах с частичной поддержкой, то всё не на столько печально.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 40px 20px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

.box::after {
    content: '2';
    position: absolute;
    font: 700 150px/0 'Teko', sans-serif;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto -35px 25px auto;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko:700" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Я бы так реализовал без `mix-blend-mode`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2b2b2b;
  color: white;
}

#main-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-wrap-mask {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.layer-down {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.layer-up,
.layer-down {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.layer-up:after,
.layer-down:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 250px;
  content: '2';
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  top: 25%;
  left: 45%;
}

.layer-up {
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.layer-down:after {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <div class="main-wrap-mask">
    <div class="layer-down"></div>
    <div class="layer-up"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Масками нас обделили, `mix-blend-mode` работает не так, как хочется, поэтому костылим как можем:

```css
.block {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  font: 30px/1.2 sans-serif;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.block:before,
.block:after {
  content: attr(data-number);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 150px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}

.block:before {
  color: blue;
}

.block:after {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" data-number="2">
  Бла
  <br>Бла
  <br>Бла
</div>
```